# ANTLR matches addition over lambda body

Tags: antlr4, greedy

I have a simple ANTLR grammar with arithmetic, boolean and lambda expressions. It incorrectly parses `fun x -> x + 1` as `(fun x -> x) + 1` rather than `fun x -> (x +1)` even though the lambda rule is on top of the addition rule.

```
expression
    : number                                                              # NumberExpr
    | bool                                                                # BooleanExpr
    | 'fun' args=ID+ '->' body=expression                                 # LambdaExpr
    | callee=expression args=expression+                                  # CallExpr
    | 'let' name=ID '=' value=expression 'in' body=expression             # LetExpr
    | name=ID                                                             # VarExpr
    | 'if' test=expression 'then' then=expression 'else' else_=expression # IfThenElseExpr
    | '(' inner=expression ')'                                            # ParensExpr
    | left=expression operator=MUL right=expression                       # MultiplicationExpr
    | left=expression operator=DIV right=expression                       # DivisionExpr
    | left=expression operator=ADD right=expression                       # AdditionExpr
    | left=expression operator=SUB right=expression                       # SubtractionExpr
    | left=expression operator=AND right=expression                       # AndExpr
    | left=expression operator=OR  right=expression                       # OrExpr
    | left=expression operator=EQ right=expression                        # EqExpr
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but using the normal precedence rules addition should have the same precedence as subtraction and multiplication as division. Also equality should probably have higher precedence than "and" and "or" because you want to be able to write `a == 1 || a == 0` without parentheses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Not *though*, but *because*.

The expression `a * b + c` is parsed as `(a * b) + c` and expression `a + b * c` as `a + (b * c)` because multiplication has higher priority.

In your case, lambda has priority over addition so that's nothing wrong that `fun x -> x + 1` was parsed as `(fun x -> x) + 1` because a higher-priority operation must be done first and lower-priority second.

Just move the lambda rule under the addition rule to fix it.